# How to set with vbscript html dropdown value as default

Tags: html, vbscript

Hey guys have her an code where i add an option to a html dropdownbox with vbscript. But i want this added option set as default how can i do this. Here is the code:

```
Sub Window_OnLoad
        ForReading = 1
        Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile _
            ("C:\Temp\CAD_Kunde.txt", ForReading)
        Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
            strLine = objFile.ReadLine
            Set objOption = Document.createElement("OPTION")
            objOption.Text = strLine
            objOption.Value = strLine
            formname.select1.Add(objOption)

        Loop
        objFile.Close
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
objOption.Selected = "selected"
```

I hope you're aware that client side VBScript is really really bad idea for any public website?

- It was developed for Internet Explorer only very long time ago.
- It's still supported only by Internet Explorer.
- Microsoft is not putting any efforts to develop new features of the client side VBScript and I won't be surprised if some future version of IE will stop supporting it.

Comment: it worked thank you very much. I use this in an HTA script not on a website.

Comment: OK, fair enough. If this solved the problem, please mark the answer as accepted by clicking the empty V icon to the left. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you put this in to the `Page_Load` event

```
DropDownList.SelectedValue = 1
```

You change the end value to the one you want.

Comment: This is VB.NET - the question is about VBScript.